# Is there a way to describe a problem that you don't currently know the answer to?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

This is easiest described via example.  I develop websites for a living and often I'll have a client point out a feature on their website.  I can break these situations into two groups:

1) Point out problem and provide solution, e.g. "People are not noticing the blue button enough.  Change its color to red."

2) Point out problem and don't provide solution, e.g. "People are not noticing the blue button enough." or even more broadly "we need to improve the blue button"

Is there a word, phrase or idiom to describe the second group?

Comment: What's wrong with _problem_?

Comment: 1) There's a *problem/ issue* (to be resolved). 2) There's a *task* to be performed. (Problem has been tackled, a solution found, and given to you to implement.) -- So where's the problem? :)

Comment: @terdon my guess is that he wants to differentiate the two to itemize his bills. I've done that kind of work, and you charge more when finding solutions than just implementing a wish.

Comment: I've seen it more in a legal context, but one word for *point out problem and don't provide solution* could be *consultation*.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, even in your first category, there is also the 'issue' that the client's suggested solution may not be the only or best solution, and/or it may be impractical, time-consuming, or other unsuitable to implement.

I think I would refer to them along the lines of:

1. Problem/Issue with a solution suggested/proposed by client
2. Problem/Issue with client asking for advice on solution

#### Later additional thought:

***solved / unsolved problem***

Answer (score 0):

When the client points out an issue and provides a desired resolution, they are not in fact presenting you with an issue, but with a task. The problem that prompted the solution is irrelevant - the proposed (and insisted upon) solution may not even solve the problem. You have simply completed a **task** and that is how I would recommend referring to the first group.

The second group can be accurately referred to by the appropriate variation on problem: issue,  challenge, bug etc.